# How do I delete all saved preferences in my libgdx project?

Tags: libgdx

I want to delete the preferences that saved my last highscore. How can I do this?

Here's how I am saving preferences at the moment:

```
prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("ZombieBird");
if (!prefs.contains("highScore")){
    prefs.putInteger("highScore", 0);
}

public static void setHighScore(int val) {
   prefs.putInteger("highScore", val);
   prefs.flush();
}
```

Comment: How do you make what? How did you save your preferences? This question is pretty much unanswerable in it's current form

Comment: No.I have highscore ,I want to reset it.To do that I must delete all preferences that are saving my highscore.I dont know how to do that

Comment: Okay, delete the file in which the preferences are stored. How do you do that? No one knows because you haven't stated what you are using to save preferences.

Comment: prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("ZombieBird");
  

  if (!prefs.contains("highScore")){
   prefs.putInteger("highScore", 0);
  }
  
 }

 public static void setHighScore(int val) {
  prefs.putInteger("highScore", val);
  prefs.flush();
 }

Comment: On Android, perhaps you're looking for [`SharedPreferences.Editor::clear`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear())?

Answer (score 8):

To delete [preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) data—

### Manually

On **desktop**, shared preferences data [is in `User/.prefs`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences#storage). Simply delete the files in it.

On **Android**, do *App Info* → *Clear data*.

### Programmatically (Android and Desktop)

If you change the Key (string) of your sharedpreferece you will lose your data. To do this, use

```
prefs.putInteger("keyString", newValue)
```

Comment: were I can find the ""app info""" (i work in eclipse()

Comment: He means on your android phone. The preferences are linked to the game internally and you cannot influence it with eclipse other then by writing code.

Answer (score 4):

To do it programmatically without having to keep track of all the keys:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences( "your_preferences_name_here" );

// Clears the values
prefs.clear();

// Saves the change
prefs.flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the Mac to delete preferences/data you need to go to:

```
~/.prefs
```

and delete you game file.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences#storage